# How to return the response of multiple asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bookshelf.js

Similar to this question : [Return response from async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
Except that the call is within a loop that calls multiple time the asynchronous function.

Specifically, how can the value of s be returned? This code returns undefined. This function is called within a for loop. The library used for ORM is Bookshelfjs. Thanks for the help.

```
function getUsernameFromDBAsync(userId) {
    var s = "moo";

    new Model.Users({
            idUser: userId
        })
        .fetch()
        .then(function(u) {
            var prenom = u.get('firstName');
            var nom = u.get('familyName');
            s = prenom + " " + nom;
            return s;
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you using a promise library? Or node 4?

Comment: whether one or multiple doesnt matter you need to have callback too handle data, cant return data as name suggests it is asynchronous.

Comment: I am using node 4. I tried promisejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aren't really showing how you're doing the loop which makes it a little harder to guess what to recommend.  But assuming `.fetch().then()` returns a promise, here's a general idea with standard ES6 promises built into node.js:

```
function getUsernameFromDBAsync(userId) {
    var s = "moo";

    return new Model.Users({
        idUser: userId
    }).fetch().then(function (u) {
        var prenom = u.get('firstName');
        var nom = u.get('familyName');
        s = prenom + " " + nom;
        return s;
    });
}

var userIds = [...];
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < userIds.length; i++) {
    promises.push(getUsernameFromDBAsync(userIds[i]));
}

// now set up a .then() handler for when all the promises are done
Promise.all(promises).then(function(names) {
    // process names array here
}, function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

If you are using the Bluebird promise library, you could do it a little bit more simply like this:

```
function getUsernameFromDBAsync(userId) {
    var s = "moo";

    return new Model.Users({
        idUser: userId
    }).fetch().then(function (u) {
        var prenom = u.get('firstName');
        var nom = u.get('familyName');
        s = prenom + " " + nom;
        return s;
    });
}

var userIds = [...];
Promise.map(userIds, getUsernameFromDbAsync).then(function(names) {
    // process names array here
}, function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Var `s` is unnecessary. Simply return the "prénom nom" string from then's success callback.

```
function getUsernameFromDBAsync(userId) {
    return new Model.Users({
        idUser: userId
    }).fetch().then(function (u) {
        return u.get('firstName') + ' ' + u.get('familyName');
    });
}
```

Your "loop" can be achieved with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate an array of promises, followed by `Promise.all(promises).then(...)`, to receive and handle an array of names when all the promises have resolved.

```
var promises = userIds.map(function(userId) {
    return getUsernameFromDBAsync(userId);
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(names) {
    // do something with `names`, which is an array of `prénom nom` strings.
}, function(err) {
    // handler error, eg ...
    console.error(error);
});
```

Or more succinctly :

```
Promise.all(userIds.map(getUsernameFromDBAsync)).then(function(names) {
    // do something with `names`, which is an array of `prénom nom` strings.
}, function(err) {
    // handler error, eg ...
    console.error(error);
});
```